# telerik grid detailtview Razor vb.net Syntax

Tags: razor, telerik-grid, vb.net-2010

I need some help with the syntax

I have the Razor code below. But I do not get the detail view ok. When I use the code below the detail grid will be rendered and after that the normal customer grid. The object is a customer and a detail view are some settings for this customer? Can someone help me with the syntax?

Thanks!

```
    @(Html.Telerik.Grid(Model) _
            .Name("CustomerGrid") _
                .DataBinding(Function(dataBinding) dataBinding.Server() _
                                        .Update("SaveCustomer", "Admin")) _
        .DataKeys(Function(keys) keys.Add(Function(o) o.CustomerID)) _
        .DetailView(Function(dt) dt.Template(Sub(tt)
                                 Html.Telerik.Grid(tt.MessageSettings) _
                                 .Name("MessageSetting" & tt.CustomerID) _
                                 .Columns(Function(dc) {
                                                dc.Bound(Function(dd) dd.CustomerMessageSettingsID), _
                                                dc.Bound(Function(dd) dd.Free)
                                              }).Render
                        End Sub)) _
        .Columns(Function(c) { _
                        c.Bound(Function(o) o.CompanyName).Width(200), _
                        c.Bound(Function(o) o.Credits), _
                        c.Bound(Function(o) o.Address), _
                        c.Bound(Function(o) o.City), _
                        c.Command(Function(d) { _
                            d.Edit.ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image) _
                        }) _
                    }) _
.Filterable _
.Groupable _
.Editable(Function(e) e.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)) _
.Pageable() _
.Sortable() _
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `LoadContentFrom()`

```
.DetailView(details => details.ClientTemplate(    
 Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
 .Items(items =>
                {
items.Add().Text("MyView").LoadContentFrom("PartialActionResult", "Controller", New With { _
        .param1 = "<#= ID#>" _
    })
 }) // End of item Tabs
                .ToHtmlString()
                ) // End of Detail View Client Template
                ) // End of Detail View
```